# How to use another class inside httpPost method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In MVC my controller (HomeController.cs) I have an httpPost actionResult method (Battle) that uses a model (ModelVariables), everything is fine except when I try including a void method from a different class (Intermediary.cs),

What I want to do: properly add any void method in my httpPost actionresult(Battle) and run properly, here's my code:

Controller (HomeController.cs):

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ModelVariables model = new ModelVariables()
        {

            CheckBoxItems = Repository.CBFetchItems(),
            CheckBoxItemsMasteries = Repository.CBMasteriesFetchItems(),
            CheckBoxItemsLevel = Repository.CBLevelFetchItems(),
            CheckBoxItemsItems = Repository.CBItemsFetchItems(),
            CheckBoxItemsFioraSLevel = Repository.CBFioraSLevelFetchItems(),
            CheckBoxItemsRunes = Repository.CBRunesFetchItems(),
            Inter = new Intermediary() //Here I instantiate other class
    };



        return View("Index", model);
    }

[HttpPost]
  public ActionResult Battle(ModelVariables model)
    {
        Inter.InstantiateRunes(model); //hmm doesent seem to work

        return View("Battle", model);
    }
```

Other class (Intermediary.cs):

```
public void InstantiateRunes(ModelVariables model)
    {
        var LifeStealQuintCount = model.CheckBoxItemsRunes.Where(x => x.CBIsSelectedRunes).Select(x => x.CBRunesID = "LS").ToList().Count;
        var LifeStealQuintValue = model.CheckBoxItemsRunes.Where(x => x.CBIsSelectedRunes && x.CBRunesID == "LS").Select(x => x.CBRunesValue).FirstOrDefault();
        if (model.CheckBoxItemsRunes != null && LifeStealQuintCount != 0 && LifeStealQuintValue != 0)
        {


            ViewBag.runeTest = LifeStealQuintValue * LifeStealQuintCount; //I set the values here, what's wrong?
        }
    }
```

View (Battle.cshtml):

```
@ViewBag.runeTest //unable to display due to void method not working
```

Summary: My code here shows no errors, yet when I run the values do not seem to travel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ViewBag` is a property of `Controller` class and setting a `ViewBag` value in your `Intermediary` class (which has no relationship to `Controller`) will not work.

You have not indicated what type `LifeStealQuintValue` is, but assuming its `int` (as `LifeStealQuintCount` is) and the the result of the multiplication will always result in `int`, then change your method to

```
public int? InstantiateRunes(ModelVariables model)
{
    var LifeStealQuintCount = model.CheckBoxItemsRunes.Where(x => x.CBIsSelectedRunes).Select(x => x.CBRunesID = "LS").ToList().Count;
    var LifeStealQuintValue = model.CheckBoxItemsRunes.Where(x => x.CBIsSelectedRunes && x.CBRunesID == "LS").Select(x => x.CBRunesValue).FirstOrDefault();
    if (model.CheckBoxItemsRunes != null && LifeStealQuintCount != 0 && LifeStealQuintValue != 0)
    {
        return LifeStealQuintValue * LifeStealQuintCount; //I set the values here, what's wrong?
    }
    return null;
}
```

and then change your POST method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Battle(ModelVariables model)
{
    ViewBag.runeTest = Inter.InstantiateRunes(model);
    return View("Battle", model);
}
```